# Enable users to create own homepage

Tags: web-development, website-design, web-hosting

Can anyone tell me based on experience what to use or what to do?

I want to enable users(my family) to create their own simple homepage including a background image, some text and hyperlinks based on templates on my website hosted on my server. What is the best way to approach this? I don’t have any website created yet so I’m open to all suggestions. I want to present them with a webbased GUI, so there is no HTML or programming knowlegde needed. It needs to have a low learing curve.

I searched the web and came across Wordpress, Movabletype and some other CMS like tools. (Joomla and such) Are these any good?

Please advice,

Darrell.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is easy to setup, and easy to use. There are tons of themes which will likely make happy your family members who want their page(s) to look cool. It's mainly blogging software, but you can create pages fairly easily with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "on my website hosted on my server". Do you mean your hardware, or the hosting account you have somewhere, or on the domain you own?

If you are just trying to get something setup on a domain you own, then [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com) might be a good option. It's part of Google Apps, so you can setup your family members as separate users each with their own email address @yourdomain and each with an area of a website at your domain that they can edit using Google's easy-to-use web based GUI.

Comment: What google sites provides is excatly what I'm looking for. But I want to host it on my own webserver. are there any other options.